# error when running "gulp "

Tags: gulp, gulp-usemin

when  I  tried to run gulp in my webapp folder  an error occured:

```
"
[14:16:06] Finished 'jshint' after 813 ms
[14:16:06] Starting 'usemin'...
Unhandled rejection Error: ϵͳ�Ҳ���ָ����·����

    at notFoundError (D:\project\datacollector\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoe
nt.js:11:11)
    at verifyENOENT (D:\project\datacollector\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoen
t.js:46:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\project\datacollector\node_modules\cross-spawn\l
ib\enoent.js:33:19)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
"
```

after than I tried to run:

```
npm cache clean gulp-usemin
```

but the error occoured again
thanks for help!

Comment: try `npm cache verify`, **if the problem still, delete npm-cache folder from %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming folder**. then retry process.

Comment: I think you are in windows, so please follow [official node-js guidelines from microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines). it is an automated way and will solve several problems.

Comment: thanks ,but npm cache verify still encounter an error:npm ERR! Usage: npm cache add <tarball file>
npm ERR! npm cache add <folder>
npm ERR! npm cache add <tarball url>
npm ERR! npm cache add <git url>
npm ERR! npm cache add <name>@<version>
npm ERR! npm cache ls [<path>]
npm ERR! npm cache clean [<pkg>[@<version>]]

Comment: **if `npm cache verify` encounter errors, there is a problem with your npm cache**. please take second step which will wipeout the npm cache from your system. optionally restart your system and reinstall node-js. then follow [official node-js guidelines from microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines). after that retry the process.